# Why divide the $L^2$ norm by 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

I am reading a paper where they try to solve some linear system of equations. Using:

$$
y = \min_x \frac{1}{2}||Dx-d||_2^2
$$

Probably a very beginner question, but I am wondering, why is the division by $2$ placed in the front? From what I gather we are trying to minimize the $L^2$ norm of the RSS. The RSS is just the squared differences between $Dx$ and $d$, and the $2$-norm also doesn't involve any division.

Comment: It's an entirely arbitrary choice. I suspect that the authors did this so that they wouldn't have to keep a factor of $2$ when considering the derivative of this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constant factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't change the location of the minimum, as you observe. The factor is there because $$\frac{d}{d\vec{x}}\left\|D\vec{x} - d\right\|^2 = 2D^T(D\vec{x}-d)$$ and hence the factor of $2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ cancel, making the expression for the derivative simpler. It's purely by convention.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask such an elementary question, but how do you prove that multiplying by a constant (in this case $\frac{1}{2}$) doesn't change the minimum?

Comment: @CasimirRönnlöf: Any value $x$ that minimizes a function $f(x)$ also minimizes the function $a f(x)$ where $a > 0$. Note that this multiplication _does_ change the _minimum_ of the function--that is, the minimum value of $a f(x)$--but not the _minimizer_, which is the value of $x$ where this occurs. FWIW, the minimizer of $f(x)$ also minimizes $f(x) + b$ for any real constant $b$. You can prove these to yourself by seeing what conclusions you can draw about $a f(x_1) < a f(x_2)$ or $f(x_1) + b < f(x_2) + b$ when it's known that $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.